# Facebook Commenst Box: can't add comments

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm adding Facebook-commenting functionality to the site. It doesn't have domain name yet, so I'm accesing it by numeric IP.
I've succeeded in showing the box with the comment adding form, and I can log in and send something. But after each send the comment just is not added.

Is numeric address a source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same situation and when I used it on a real domain, it works. Somehow it does not work on ip server. Better you move the site to live domain and try again and it should work :)